# How to annotate an optional class variable

Tags: python, annotations, type-hinting, python-typing

In Python 3 how do you add type annotations for a class variable that may or may not exist. This is distinct from a class variable that may be `None`. For example:

```
from typing import Optional

class Foo:
  a: Optional[int]
  # b: ???

  def __init__(self, has_a: bool, has_b: bool):
    if has_a:
      self.a = 1
    else
      self.a = None

    if has_b:
      self.b = 2
```

Then

```
>>> x = Foo(False, False)
>>> repr(x.a)
'None'
>>> repr(x.b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'b'
```

What do I write in `???` to indicate to type checkers that `b` may be an `int` or it may not exist at all?

Comment: Are you looking for [`Union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union)? - `Union[int,None]`

Comment: Actually [`Optional`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional) (which is equivalent to the above) (and you're already using)

Comment: Doing `b: int` doesn't actually define `b`, so it seems to give the behavior you want...

Comment: @Sayse: No I'm not looking for `Optional`. A class variable that isn't defined is different to one that is `None`, and accessing it doesn't return `None` - it throws an exception. That's what my example demonstrates.

Comment: @Tomerikoo: Ah wait, I misunderstood you. Yes I can do `b: int`, but then the type checker won't complain if I just do `self.b` without checking `hasattr(self, 'b')` first. But you might be right that that is the best you can do at the moment.

Comment: Yeah I don't think a type checker should do that. It checks for types, not existence. I t will complain if you're using `self.b` in the wrong context type-wise, not that you didn't check if it exists first...

Comment: There's no reason a type checker couldn't do this. Non-existence can be a type in the same way that never returning from a function is a type.

Comment: Though given that you can't even type `kwargs` properly I guess I shouldn't be surprised that you can't do this.